# How can I make the Timer run without freezing on page

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm making the slashscreen page of xamarin welcome page.

I want to implement timer which will close `SlashScreen` after 5 seconds.
And showing the seconds in the xaml.

```
<Label TextColor="Black" FontSize= "20"  Text="{Binding timerSecond}"/>
```

Here is my class:

```
public partial class SlashScreen : ContentPage
{
    int timerSecond = 5;

    public SlashScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        timer.Start();
        timer.Elapsed += (obj, args) =>
        {

            if (timerSecond == 0)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
            }
            else
            {
                timerSecond--;
            }
        };

    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to declare the timer at the class level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not tested. but it should work for you

```js
        public partial class SlashScreen : ContentPage
        {
            int _timerSecound = 5;
            public SlashScreen()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            protected override void OnAppearing()
            {
                Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
                {
                        _timerSecound --;
                        timeSecound.Text = _timerSecound.ToString();
                        if (_timerSecound <=0){ 
                        /// your code here, 
                        // i dont know if you could create a new mainpage, this should not work.
                        Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
                        // dont know if this will work for you, but this will close 
                        // the current and go back too the prev screen
                        this.Navigation.PopAsync ();
                        this.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
                        return false; // stop
                      }
                      return true; // repeat
                };
            }
        }
```

Comment: Toma i dont know why after this, it give me blank page. And it didnt change the timer text at all.

Comment: I dont know the reason man, There is nothing spec with the timer. debug it and see whats happning. try to add a default text for `timeSecound` and se if you could see it, when the page appear

Comment: Toma the default can be see but just not changing.

Comment: Dose the `Elapsed ` trigger?  if no then try to move the timer inside `SlashScreen()` I think that `SlashScreen()` trigger before `OnAppearing` or move `timer.Start();` inside `OnAppearing`

Comment: Toma yes it has been triggered

Comment: And the _timerSecound sometime will become negative.

Comment: Ok after i read about this, i came to relize that when you need to intract with th ui you need to use `Windows.UI.Xaml.DispatcherTimer` instead. i updated my answer it should work now. i hop :)

Comment: the time will stop when its `_timerSecound <= 0`.

Comment: Toma I'm using xamarin and its do not have this class=(

Comment: hahah updated my answer. read here about xamarin.forms timer. https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-timer/

Comment: `this.Navigation.PopAsync ();
                        this.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();` but this have to remove

Comment: yeh its upp yo you to remove them i added them as an example. i dont know if you are using navigation or not.